# How to setup Pivotal Cloud Foundry Config Server to use multiple search paths from my git repo?

Tags: cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-config, configserver

I have a local config server and it works okay with yml configurations setup like this?

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/xxx/xxxxx
          search-paths:
          - 'kenya*' 
          - 'tanzania*' 
          - 'uganda*' 
          - 'congo*'
          - 'zimbabwe*'
```

In my local project, I can access all of these repos like

http://localhost:8888/uganda/dev

This returns the correct files with the selected profile ad expected.

However when I setup the Pivotal Config server, I only get the default properties regardless of what parameters I add to the path.

Something like this https://configserver.cfapps.io/uganda/dev only returns the default properties at the root of the repo.

How can I use the

> searchPaths Stated here https://docs.run.pivotal.io/spring-cloud-services/config-server/configuring-with-git.html

flag to add all my sub folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Pivotal Spring Cloud Services, you can create a service using multiple `searchPaths` like this:

```
cf create-service -c '{ "git": { "uri": "https://github.com/dmikusa-pivotal/cook-config.git", "label": "search-paths", "searchPaths": "dev,prod" } }' cook-config-server
```

The `searchPaths` argument just takes a comma separated list of search paths/patterns.

The repository that you're pointed to, should then have top level folders called `dev` and `prod`. Config server will then return `<app-name>.properties` (all all the other variations it supports) from within the search path folder.

You can validate that you're receiving multiple search paths worth of data, by running a command like this:

```
curl -k -H "Authorization: bearer $(curl -k -s -X POST 'https://p-spring-cloud-services.uaa.<system_domain>/oauth/token' -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<insert client id>&client_secret=<insert client_secret>' | jq .access_token | cut -d '"' -f 2)" <insert uri>/cook/prod
```

You need to replace `<system_domain>` with the system domain for your foundation, `<insert client id>` and `<insert client secret>` with your service instance's client id and secret (run `cf env <app>` against an app that has a bound SCS Config server to get these values).

This command will do two things. First, it will use the `client_id` and `client_secret` to fetch a token. The token is then used in a second request to actually request some data from the config server.

You should see output like this, if you're getting config from multiple search paths (note how there's data from `dev` and `prod` subfolders):

```
{"name":"cook","profiles":["prod"],"label":null,"version":"5d5a3f26022dd00becdbad855c7d27ae530685f7","state":null,"propertySources":[{"name":"https://github.com/dmikusa-pivotal/cook-config.git/prod/cook.properties","source":{"cook.special":"Prod Config"}},{"name":"https://github.com/dmikusa-pivotal/cook-config.git/dev/cook.properties","source":{"cook.special":"Dev Config"}},{"name":"https://github.com/dmikusa-pivotal/cook-config.git/cook.properties","source":{"cook.special":"Not in Folder config"}}]}
```

Hope that helps!